# Firebase RTDB trigger not fired from Flutter Firebase SDK triggering event

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an application in Flutter and during development, I encountered this anomaly.

On Firebase Realtime Database I have a simple trigger for testing the functionality, the trigger is this:

```
/**
 * Triggered by a change to a Firebase RTDB reference.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */
exports.helloRTDB = (event, context) => {
  const resource = context.resource;
  // log out the resource string that triggered the function
  console.log('Function triggered by change to: ' +  resource);
  // now log the full event object
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
};
```

> (*Function name*: createGame)
>
> *Function to execute*: helloRTDB
>
> *Trigger type*: Firebase Realtime Database (beta)
>
> *Event type*: create
>
> *Database*: my-db
>
> *Path*: /lobby/{userId}

When I run this from *Cloud Functions Testing* on *Google Cloud Platform* works well but this does not work when I run the triggering event from *Flutter - Firebase Database SDK*.

**Cloud Functions Testing:**

[image]

**Flutter - Firebase Database SDK:**

```
class FirebaseLobbyRepository {
  final lobbyCollection = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('lobby');

  Future<void> test() {
    return lobbyCollection.set('test'); // This work but attached trigger not.
  }
}
```

**When I call test() method the record is added in the RTDB but the trigger is not fired! Why?**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like you're defining the Cloud Function purely in the Cloud console, not using the Firebase tools. If that's the case, can you show how you set up the triggering condition for this Cloud Functions?

Comment: As @Frank van Puffelen mentioned, it seems that you are defining a Google Cloud Function. To define a Firebase Cloud Function, you need to import the modules 'firebase-functions' and 'firebase-admin' and these are not shown in the snippet of code. Let me know if you are using the document https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions or a different one, to try to understand what the issue is.